# Mongoose $match nested array with query values or return all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, backend

Main task: apply tags filters for products (could be one or multiple).

Need to return filtered products list with specified dietary tags in query.
Product tags field is a ref to tags collection.

$lookup and related stages:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'tags',
    localField: 'tags',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'tags',
    pipeline: [
      {
        $project: {
          tags: '$tags',
          _id: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
{ $unwind: { path: '$tags', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{
  $addFields: {
    tags: '$tags.tags',
  },
},
```

Output product if tags collection has ref tags id. Else tags field doesn't exist.

```
{
  "_id": "65543472bde41c7561151fd3",
  "slug": "green-olives",
  "name": "Green Olives",
  "description": "Some description",
  "category": "food-cupboard",
  "subCategory": "canned-vegetables"
  "popularity": 76,
  "views": 327,
  "rating": 5,
  "tags": {
    "dietaries": [
      "HALAL"
    ],
    "promotions": [
      "PWP"
    ]
  },
}
```

Expected (conjectural) aggregation $match stage:

```
{
  $match: {
    // if query "tags" exist => filter products which have (tags.dietaries) with query values
    // if query "tags" doesn't exist => all product with tags field and without it
  }
}
```

Tried match 'tags.dietaries' array with regex if dietary (query) exists, else return all. The problem is products returns but only with existing tags field.

```
{
  $match: {
    'tags.dietaries': dietary
      ? {
          $regex: dietary.split('+').join('|'),
        }
      : /.*/,
  },
},
```

Another idea is to use $cond operator but couldn't apply it properly.

Also I thought keeping tags field null by default that way making possible/improving matching tags.
Is it good idea?

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on the specifics of your question. Can you create and share a link to an example on mongoplayground.net?

Comment: Sure. Look this
[link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jZSZ4UqldGF).

Should i edit question with more details? Which side should be better described?

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood i made this aggregation,

I took the liberty to remove the unwind stage because i didn't see a use for it,and i noticed that you have a one to one relationship so i just took the first item .

and if i understood you filtering criteria correctly you want to filter by the dietaries if the tag is available if not to just return everything ,

I hope my understanding is on point if not leave me some comment so we can tweak the aggregation .

```json
[{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tags",
      "localField": "tags",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "tags"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tags": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$tags.tags",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dietariesIntersectionSize": {
        "$size": {
          "$ifNull": [{
              "$setIntersection": [
                /// the array of the query
                [
                  "HALAL",
                  "GLUTEN_FREE"
                ],
                "$tags.dietaries"
              ]
            },
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [{
          "tags": {
            "$eq": null
          }
        },
        {
          "dietariesIntersectionSize": {
            "$gt": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

]
```

I hope that was helpful

Comment: Thank you for fast reply!
Yes, you understood correctly.
I applied your technique in $lookup and $addFields stages and it works perfect.

But I couldn't apply $match stage. Now method returns always all products without filtering. I'd tried to pass array of strings or just string (one tag) into $in operator. Look please example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NdktU6xUDw2).

Perhaps I incorrectly described the desired result. If so, please tell me, I will try to describe in other words.

Comment: ok i updated the aggregation , now i made the tweaks so you can filter with more than one item , if i misunderstood anything let me know

Comment: Almost in target. A few tweaks please:
If the array of the query is empty return all products (with tags field and without it).
If the array of the query has 1 or more tags return only filtered products with tags field which contains query tags (products without tags field should be ignored).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like crutchy but works fine.

```
{
 $match: {
  'tags.dietaries': {
    $in: dietary ? dietary.split('+') : [null, /.*/],
  },
 },
},
```

Description:

1. If query exists ('HALAL+GLUTEN_FREE') return documents which 'tags.dietaries' tags array contains one of query tags array: `$in: dietary ? dietary.split('+')`
2. Else return documents where 'tags.dietaries' field exists and doesn't: `: [null, /.*/]`

Thanks [Abdellatif Sraiti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12401388/abdellatif-sraiti) for help. He turned me in the right direction.
Hope helps someone.

P.S. I would be grateful if someone could share a better solution